# Хранение различных постов

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте есть 3 раздела, в первом располагаются посты, во 2 располагается галерея с описанием и названием для каждой записи, в 3-м разные новости. Вопрос есть ли в вордпрессе встроенные механизмы хранения/редактирования различных типов постов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress поддерживает кастомные типы записей (постов). Их используют для поддержания собственного содержимого и управления им. Например, для создания портфолио проектов, акций, партнеров и т.д. Самый широко используемый магазин на WordPress - плагин WooCommerce - использует кастомный тип записей "товар".

Подробнее о кастомных типах записей можно почитать на русском [здесь](https://wpcafe.org/tutorials/rukovodstvo-po-kastomnyim-tipam-zapisey-wordpress/).